# Actor model to replace the threading model?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I read a chapter in a book (Seven languages in Seven Weeks by Bruce A. Tate) about Matz (Inventor of Ruby) saying that 'I would remove the thread and add actors, or some other more advanced concurrency features'.

- Why and how an actor model can be an advanced concurrency model that replaces the threading?
- What other models are the 'advanced concurrency model'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not so much that the actor model will replace threads; at the level of the cpu, processes will still have multiple threads which are scheduled and run on the processor cores.  The idea of actors is to replace this underlying complexity with a model which, its proponents argue, makes it easier for programmers to write reliable code.

The idea of actors is to have separate threads of control (processes in Erlang parlance) which communicate exclusively by message passing.  A more traditional programming model would be to share memory, and coordinate communication between threads using mutexes.  This still happens under the surface in the actor model, but the details are abstracted away, and the programmer is given reliable primitives based on message passing.

One important point is that actors do not necessarily map 1-1 to threads -- in the case of Erlang, they definitely don't -- there would normally be many Erlang processes per kernel thread.  So there has to be a scheduler which assigns actors to threads, and this detail is also abstracted away from the application programmer.

If you're interested in the actor model, you might want to take look at the way it works in [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)) or [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)).

If you're interested in other types of new concurrency hotness, you might want to look at [software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory), a different approach that can be found in clojure and haskell.

It bears mentioning that many of the more aggressive attempts at creating advanced concurrency models appear to be happening in functional languages.  Possibly due to the belief (I drink some of this kool-aid myself) that immutability makes concurrency much easier.

Comment: I'd go further and say that immutability increases system robustness. Concurrency is one dimension of software complexity where the difference in robustness is very obvious. Very complex systems can benefit from using immutability even without needing to satisfy concurrency issues.

Comment: Also, remember that the actor model can also be applied in a network, to develop an asynchronous model of request processing. In fact, given that multi-core is going to be the rule, this abstraction might even be interesting in a os api level (at least it is for me).

Answer (score 3):

I made this question my favorite and am waiting for answers, but since there still isn't, here is mine..

> Why and how an actor model can be an
>   advanced concurrency model that
>   replaces the threading?

Actors can get rid of mutable shared state, which is very difficult to code right. (My understanding is that) `actors` can basically thought as objects with their own thread(s). You send messages between actors that will be queued and consumed by the thread within the actor. So, whatever state in the actor is encapsulated, and will not be shared. So it is easy to code right.

see also http://www.slideshare.net/jboner/state-youre-doing-it-wrong-javaone-2009

> What other models are the 'advanced
>   concurrency model'?

see http://www.slideshare.net/jboner/state-youre-doing-it-wrong-javaone-2009

Answer (score 2):

See **Dataflow Programming**. It's an approach, which is a layer over top of the usual OOP design. In some words:

- there are a scene, where *Components* resides;
- Components have *Ports*: *Producers* (output, which generate messages) and *Consumers* (input, which process messages);
- there are *Messages* pre-defined between Components: one Component's Producer port is bind with another's Consumer.

The programming is going on 3 layer:

- writing the dataflow system (language, framework/server, component API),
- writing Components (system, basic, and domain-oriented ones),
- creating the dataflow program: placing components into the scene, and define messages between them.

Wikipedia articles are good starting point to understand the business: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming 
See also "actor model", "dataflow programming" etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that I would call Dataflow a layer over OOP, more an alternative to OOP with some conceptual crossover. You could say OOP as per Smalltalk is a message-oriented language which is what Dataflow is about.

Comment: Implementation of a dataflow system requires OOP (or at least, it's the recommended, natural way), depending of the DF architecture. I've written a DF system, where the dispatcher and components are written in C++, the connections and parameters are defined using a propiatery script language, which is compiled to C++ code, and the final result is an a.out/ELF executable. So, the underlying architecture is OOP, the DF system is built on it. (Classes: Message, Port, Consumer, Producer, Component (abstract) etc. and of course lot of component classes).

Answer (score 1):

Please the following paper

[Actor Model of Computation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1459)

Answer (score 1):

Also please see

[ActorScript(TM) extension of C#(TM), Java(TM), and Objective C(TM): iAdaptive(TM) concurrency for antiCloud(TM) privacy and securitY](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2748)

Comment: At first I thought this was a joke, considering all the trademarks in the title.